# Making a C++ application "Opened with..."

Tags: c++, windows, file, associations

I'm working on a (C++) program that more or less revolves around renaming files. I would like to make it so that you can select a file, right-mouse click it and select "Open With" and then select my application.
I got the context menu part figured out, I just don't know how to do the C++ part.

In other words, how to make a program (in C++) that can be opened together with a file (so by context menu or directly opening it) and process this file?

Example:
In my Windows, I associate the ".roberto" extension with "*C:\Program Files\MyProgram\MyProgram.exe*". So if I open a ".roberto" file, a command prompt pops up, only displaying the name of the selected file.

I hope this is clear, I am not sure how to explain this. I also had some trouble with searching on this question, so please forgive me if this has been asked before.
Thanks.

Comment: c++ does not have anything in the standard that deals with this OS specific feature. What framework are you using? winapi, MFC, Qt ...?

Comment: If I recall correctly, the selection is passed in `argv`. It's been a long time since I did something like that, though.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what framework I'm using... How do I know this? I write in Visual Studio Express 2013 and I try to leave settings as they are.   : P

Comment: I gave the `argv` a go. I made a new program and left the default `int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])` still in place and had all the `argv` elements printed. I get one argument when opened directly and two arguments when opened with the 'Open with...' dialogue. However, the content of these `argv` items is just random letters and numbers, like a pointer.

Comment: Oh, solved it. Changing `_TCHAR*` to just `char*` solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

Using the arguments given to main was the clue. The following program prints one line if opened directly, this line is the path of the program itself, and if opened with the 'Open with...' options it also shows the selected file.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cout << "Argument count: " << argc << endl << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        cout << argv[i] << endl;
    }

    cout << endl << endl << endl << endl;

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On **Windows** platform in **MFC**-based application this is done automatically by framework in `InitInstance()` method of your application class:

```
EnableShellOpen();
RegisterShellFileTypes(TRUE);
```

**IMPORTANT:** In general this functionality is framework dependent and OS speicific.

Comment: I don't really understand this. How would I use it? How would I get the file path I'm looking for?